# favicon.svg with base64 encoded .ttf font file doesn't display text in Chrome, works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

My `favicon.svg` displays in Firefox, but not Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
  @font-face {font-family: "MyFont";src: url(MyFont.ttf) format("truetype");}
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
</html>
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
        src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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) 
               format('truetype');
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="MyFont">A</text>
</svg>
```

When loaded directly, the above image loads as expected in both Chrome and Firefox. However, **when loading the above html, the icon only appears in Firefox, the icon doesn't appear in Chrome. What have I gotten wrong?**

---

<sup>`favicon.svg` uses a base64 encoded `.ttf` font file, which I minimised: `pyftsubset AndroidClock.ttf --unicodes=U+0041 --output-file=/tmp/a.ttf && base64 /tmp/a.ttf > /tmp/t`. The image is then constructed from letter `A` of that font.</sup>

<sup>Google Chrome 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 80.0 (64-bit) on Linux.</sup>

Comment: Note that Chrome's implementation is new. Perhaps it's buggy. Maybe try raising a bug on Chrome's bugtracker unless someone's already raised one.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a Chrome bug, but I discovered a workaround: the webfont in the favicon works if you also include the same SVG in an `<img>` tag, even a hidden one.

```html
<img src="favicon.svg" style="display: none">
```

(If you then remove the `<img>` tag, it keeps working anyway until you exit Chrome, which made this frustrating to debug.)

I’ve filed this as [Chromium bug 1140920](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1140920).

You probably also want to correct `data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,` to `data:font/ttf;base64,`, since `font/truetype` isn’t a valid MIME type and `font/ttf` doesn’t have a charset.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 This partially works for me: A favicon appears, but it's rendered in the wrong font. (I've edited my minimal example to include a line I inadvertently omitted.)

Comment: @user2768 With this workaround, Chrome shows the same result as Firefox for me, and it does appear to be the ‘A’ glyph from your embedded font. I’ve added a screenshot of what I see. If that’s not what you expect, maybe check the original font and your subsetting process? [This `AndroidClock.ttf`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/fonts/AndroidClock.ttf) has no ‘A’ glyph at all. You probably also want to correct `data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,` to `data:font/ttf;base64,`.